# Is it guaranteed that the array specified always get enough space?

Tags: c, arrays

Unlike the `malloc` , I have never seen a `if` statement for checking whether the array has got enough space. So is it guranteed that the arrays always get enough space even though they are allocated in the stack? And what to do in case otherwise?

Comment: Either it fits on the stack, or your programme crashes. Allocating an array on the stack just means adjusting the stack pointer.

Comment: UB. There need not be a stack at all. In fact the word stack never even appears in the standard (not even once!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No guarantee at all.

There's no way to verify whether the stack allocation was successful or not. The C standard doesn't mandate any limits (min or max).

So you should check with your operating system which typically allocates a fixed size stack. For example, on my Ubuntu system, the stack size is `1MB`. So it depends on your operating system.

In fact, if you start to have doubts whether stack size is enough, you should go for dynamic allocation (`malloc`).

Comment: Even though the question at first sounded like a noob one, it is indeed a sad realization that the standard says nothing about the array allocation.

Comment: Indeed. But I am sure, the language committee would have certainly come across this issue and would have decided that if a developer is using such a large stack allocated memory, there's some serious problem with the code/design.

Comment: Either that, or there is no good way to standardize array allocation on the stack. It doesn't make sense in this case to use the same behavior on a supercomputer and on an embedded device.

Comment: Not only can the stack size depend on the OS, many UNIXs allow the sys. admin. to alter the hard and soft limits; and there is `ulimit -s`, the `RLIMIT_STACK` resource limit.  So different users can have different stack size limits.

Answer (score 0):

The array will always get enough space either **valid or invalid** i.e. if the stack doesn't have sufficient space, then there is a good possibility that you might using some other memory earmarked for some other purpose. In such cases your program will lead to **undefined behavior** ( [Stack Overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) :) )

Comment: I'm looking at the C99 standard section 6.7.5.2 and it doesn't really specify if the array should be allocated or not. I know it is absurd, and I know no compiler is crazy enough to not allocate the array on the stack, but if the standard doesn't specify it...

Comment: Not to mention the word `stack` is never used in the standard, so in a certain architecture it may not even exist

Comment: I am not aware of any such practice where a local scope array is not allocated on stack. Let's see if some other interesting answer pops up. If it does, it will be a good learning. : )

Comment: Me neither, but I am pretty sure there _are_ architectures that don't use stack. But even if not, since the standard doesn't specify it, you can't count on it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you define the array.

For example:

```
int foo[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
int bar[10] = { 1, 0 };
int fee[10];
```

In the above example, the array `foo` will contain three entries with the contents of the assignment. The array `bar` on the other hand will contain ten entries, the first initialized to `1` and the rest as zero. The array `fee` will contain ten entries as well, but the contents is uninitialized and will most likely appear random.

However, like memory allocated by `malloc` the end of the arrays the arrays can be overwritten. For example you can do `foo[4] = 4;`, but this will overwrite memory outside the array and might even result in a crash.

So an array will always have as many entries (or as much memory how you see it) as you declare it to have, and in the example of `foo` above will have exactly enough space for the data you assign to it.

Answer (score 0):

No there is nothing in the standard which allows for this, and by the way it does not just apply to arrays, it applies to all C variables.  If the stack overflows then it will crash your program.  Dead.  Over use of recursion can have this effect, for example.
To add a complication, are you asking about 'classic' ANSI C arrays, whose size is fixed at compliation time, or C99 Variable Length Arrays (VLAs), whose size can be set at runtime?
Although VLAs look attractive, their lack of runtime checking is a distinct disadvantage over malloc, as you suggest.

Comment: oh! yes. meant only ANSI. I have little idea on the VLA. Can you help me on that please. would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: If I have seen that correctly the current ANSI standard for C is now ISO C11.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, `malloc` will attempt to allocate space and then you can use an `if` condition to check if the pointer to the array was malloc-ed successfully:

```
if (ptr == NULL) {
   printf("Error");
   exit();
}
```